# ¿Cómo registrar en dos tablas al mismo tiempo?

Tags: mysql, sql

Un procedimiento almacenado tal que una vez se inserte una nueva entrada en la tabla blog, registre en la tabla notificación que se ha ingresado a nueva entrada.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ALGO(IN info tipo, IN info1 tipo, IN info2 tipo)
BEGIN START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO TABLA1  VALUES(info, info1, info2);    
INSERT INTO
TABLA2 VALUES(info, info1, info2);

END;
```

Lo que no se es como en la segunda tabla registrar lo de la primera

Estructura de las tablas

- blog(id_blog, fecha, autor, titulo, contenido).
- notificación(id, id_blog, fecha, notificación).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @BetaM Lo siento he mirado como es la sintaxis pero no entiendo como saco la informacion del primer registro para insertarlo en el otro

Comment: @BetaM Listo eso es lo que he intentado

Comment: @BetaM Si exacto

Comment: @BetaM Son parecidos  ya agregue la estructura es muy basico a mi parecer

Comment: @BetaM voy a subir la estructura tal cual la tengo en mysql workbench para mayor claridad

Comment: @BetaM Listo ya creo que con las imagenes respondo tus preguntas creo

Comment: @franciscoayala creo que lo que buscas es un *trigger after insert*.

Comment: @cooper voy a investigar Gracias por la info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado lo que expones en los comentarios, no creo que un procedimiento almacenado sea la mejor opción, en cambio te sugiero leer sobre los [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html),  los cuales actuarán en alguno de los dos siguientes momentos:

- before
- after

En este caso lo que nos ocupa es que después de registra en una tabla se proceda con la inserción en otra:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER registraNotificacion AFTER INSERT ON blog
FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO notificacion(id_blog, fecha, notificacion)
        VALUES
        (NEW.id_blog, CURDATE(), 'Aqui lo que planeas que se almacene en la notificacion');
    END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Con esto lograrías que:

- Cada que se inserta un registro en blog, inmediatamente se tomen algunos valores de esa tabla y se inserten en notificación

Comment: Gracias estaba leyendo sobre esto me has ayudado bastante