# Trigger insert con inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Necesito hacer un trigger que me permita hacer un insert a una tabla con datos que se encuentran contenidos en otra tabla
Despues de insertar en esta tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito insertar en esta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Incluyendo los datos de esta otra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente tengo asi mi codigo

```
BEGIN
   -- Insert record into audit table
   
   INSERT INTO Movimientos
   ( fecha,
     No_Pedido,
     Id_producto,
     Cantidad,
     Id_cliente)
   
   VALUES
   (    SELECT p.Fecha, NEW.No_Pedido, det.Id_producto, det.cantidad, p.Id_cliente
       FROM detalle_pedido AS det INNER JOIN pedido AS p ON det.No_Pedido = p.No_Pedido; 
   );

END
```

Cabe resaltar que este codigo está sacado de
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Por lo cual no esta el after insert.

El error que me da el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo registrar en dos tablas al mismo tiempo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/392673/c%c3%b3mo-registrar-en-dos-tablas-al-mismo-tiempo)

Comment: Y qué pasa con el código actual? Qué error sale? Cuál es el resultado?

Comment: Acabo de colocar el error dentro del contenido

Comment: esta bien que sea asi el insert into? no sobra el values ahi?

Comment: El insert te funciona fuera del trigger?

Comment: Lo he eliminado, pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: El insert funciona, solo con los datos de la tabla, el problema esta en que tambien necesito información de la tabla pedido para almacenar esa información, mi duda es como jalar los datos de la tabla pedido para inclurlo en el insert

Comment: y tira el mismo error?

Comment: Si, sigue sin funcionar